# Disable Chrome "Restore pages? Chrome didn't shut down correctly" and other browser messages

Tags: puppeteer

This is the popup I'm referring to:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent chrome from showing these popups? I've tried using `--user-data-dir`.

Here are all the flags that I use:

```
const chromeSwitches = [
      `--user-data-dir=${tasksDataDirPath+'\\'+taskName}`,
      `--remote-debugging-port=${availablePort}`,
      "--arc-disable-locale-sync",
      "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process",
      "--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages",
      "--disable-background-timer-throttling",
      "--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows",
      "--disable-renderer-backgrounding",
      "--no-first-run",
      "--password-store=basic",
      "--use-mock-keychain",
      "--disable-extensions",
      "--disable-default-apps",
      "--disable-features=Translate",
      "--disable-background-networking",
      "--disable-sync",
      "--metrics-recording-only",
      "--mute-audio",
      "--no-default-browser-check",
      "--enable-remote-debugging"
    ];
```

Comment: `--disable-session-crashed-bubble`

Answer (score 6):

chrome 113 - this command line worked for me:

```
--hide-crash-restore-bubble
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this file manually/programmatically before staring Chrome

On Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences`

On Linux: `/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome/default/Preferences`

On MacOS: `Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable chrome running in the background. Go to chrome settings then click on **System**. Then disable continue running background...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).